# How to show the repeated element in my case

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a easy ng-repeat in my app based on the value I passed

I have something like

Js

```
$scope.total = 5;
```

Html

```
<div ng-repeat='total in total'>
    static content
</div>
```

How do I use `ng-repeat` to show 5 divs in my case? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to use ng-repeat:

Js

```
//define an array
$scope.total = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

Html

```
<div ng-repeat='number in total'>
    {{number}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use an ng-repeat it must pass in an Array object.  You can either pre-define this object like:

```
$scope.total = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
```

or by defining it inline:

```
<div ng-repeat="character in ['a','b','c','d','e']">
    {{character}}
</div>
```

There are a lot of cools things you can do with the [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) directive like checking the $index or $odd/$even property of the iterable item.  The documentation is very nice for discovering what all you can do, check it out [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

Answer (score 0):

Make total an array:

```
$scope.total = new Array(5);
```